# Showing measure values as "not applicable" which are not related to dimensions

Tags: ssas

I have a requirement where report should show measures as "not applicable" if one selects a attribute which is not linked to that measure Group.

1) unrelateddimesnion= 'false' is not solving my problem because i have few default members.

2) I could able to show measure value as "not applicable " by Writing this MDX statement

([Customer].[customer name].[customer name], [measures].[sales forecast]) = 'not applicable'

but with this i have to repeat the same line for each and every attribute present in the dimension ( and also for each and every measure present in the measure Group)

can someone help me Writing the MDX for entire dimension instead for individual attribute.  Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Mah

Answer (score 0):

Bad news! An MDX script on your cube can't reference such a sub-cube in a simple way.  You may have seen the [LEAVES(dimension) function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/leaves-mdx?view=sql-server-2017) for a scope statement but that won't work when one attribute in a dimension has the [All] level and another has a selection.  (That is to say the function returns the leaves of the dimension's *key attribute*).  What you can do is use nested scope statements with the outer one filtering down to the list of measures you want to affect.  That will at least save you typing a formula num_attributes * num_measures times.  The scope statement may even accept the [MEASUREGROUPMEASURES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/measuregroupmeasures-mdx?view=sql-server-2016) function.  (When I last used that it only returned visible measures but that's probably what you want anyway.)

It may be easier to link measure group and dimension and let your data sit on the UNKNOWN member. (Or an explicit dummy member.)  Then filters against or slices to real customer hierarchy values will exclude your [Sales Forecast] rows and show it as null. That's not something I've done and it'll have ramifications for error processing and you'll have to allow users sight of the unknown or dummy member.  So recommend you play with the idea before you rely on it.
I hope this helps some.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186386/discussion-on-answer-by-zernager-showing-measure-values-as-not-applicable-whic).